# How to read word by word from file?

Tags: android, file, cpu-word, bufferedreader

Could anybody post here some code how can I read word by word from file? I only know how to read line by line from file using BufferedReader. I'd like if anybody posted it with BufferedReader.

**I solved it with this code:**

```
    StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
                int i=0;
                Scanner input = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(a.getInputStream()));
                while(input.hasNext()) {
                    i++;
                    if(i==prefNamePosition){
                        word.append(prefName);
                        word.append(" ");
                        input.next();
                    }
                    else{
                        word.append(input.hasNext());
                        word.append(" ");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Yes of course I forgot it. I can use it. But there is one problem. I edited Q, look at there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to replace the nth token with a special value, try this:

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
    String currentWord = input.next();
    if(++i == prefNamePosition) {
        currentWord = prefName;
    }
    word.append(currentWord);
    word.append(" ");
}
```

Comment: I solved it yesterday with one small change which you can see up. But thank you for your advice to using Scanner. 

btw. It works with your code, too.

Answer (score 1):

There's no good way other than to read() and get a character at a time until you get a space or whatever criteria you want for determining what a "word" is.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to employ a tokenizer (e.g. in Java) and using the delimiter space character (i.e. ' '). Then just iterate through the tokens to read each word from your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can read lines and then use splits. There is no clear definition of word but if you want the ones separated by blank spaces you can do it.

You could also use regular expressions to do this.

Comment: No, this is not what I need. I need to read word by while loop, because when loop repeats for example fourth I need to replace fourth word.

Comment: you can store the line in a variable and then iterate with a while lopp the line, "word" by "word". and do the process you want to do.